# Library not compile with project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

In project I used library org.json. Everything works fine in the editor. When I build the project, move the "out" folder to another machine (Debian), and run Main.class via console, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
        at gro.nn.lead_updater.Config.<init>(Config.java:30)
        at gro.nn.lead_updater.Config.getInstance(Config.java:23)
        at gro.nn.lead_updater.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

I don't see any changes before and after adding the library in the out folder.
Project structure below

[image: Here project dependencies]

[image: Project structure]

Comment: You also need to have the library on the classpath when running your application.

Comment: pls, tell me how to run app in debian machine with dependency org/json in jar file. Others classes with .class

Comment: @markRotteveel, i tried use java -cp <jar name> com.company.Main . Its not help

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html. You need to create the artifact jar with all the dependencies included in it (with the class files from the jars as well). See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.

Comment: You need to use `java -cp <your-jar-name>;<other-jar-name> com.company.Main`, or if it is an executable jar, `java -jar <your-jar-name>` and make sure that the other libraries are listed in the the `Class-Path` manifest entry, and that those libraries are in the right relative location.